# fillRect with Background image in Canvas object

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

using Canvas object FillRect method is it possible to put background image on rectangle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [patterns](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-context-2d-createpattern):

Example:

```
  var pattern = context.createPattern(image, repetition);
  context.fillStyle = pattern;
  context.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
```