# How would I fillRect with an image?

Tags: javascript, image, canvas

Normally you can fill a rectangle in a canvas with`ctx.fillStyle = "whatever color here"` and then `ctx.fillRect(cords and length and width here)`. Is there a syntax where I can say `ctx.fillRect(someImagePathHere, xOfTopLeft, yofTopLeft)`

If not, how else can I achieve this?

Comment: drawImage with appropriate arguments...?

Comment: drawImage : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but possibly helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953844/fillrect-with-backgroud-image-in-canvas-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick example of how you can use `drawImage` to draw an image to a canvas. The element on the left is the image, the element on the right is the canvas with the image drawn on it.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gw8ncg7g/

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var img = document.getElementById("image");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}
```

```css
canvas {
    border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
}
```

```html
<img id="image" width="300" height="300" src="http://i.imgur.com/LDR6AWn.png?1">
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="300" >
```

Comment: The syntax is `drawImage(image, dx, dy)`, where dx and dy are the coordinates on the canvas of the top left corner of the image. `drawImage` also supports drawing the image scaled - see more details here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage

Answer (score 16):

The question is ambiguous as there are many ways to "fillRect with an image".

First off images in the browser are downloaded asynchronously so you need to wait for an image to load before you can use it. For canvas situations the most common way to get an image is to create a new [`Image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement) and set an `onload` listener

```
const img = new Image();
img.onload = someFunctionToCallWhenTheImageHasLoaded
img.src = 'http://url/to/image';
```

Then the question is what do mean by "fillRect"

Using this 256x256 image

[image]

For example to draw the image at the size it was downloaded you can use [`drawImage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) with 3 arguments

```
ctx.drawImage(img, x, y);
```

[image]

```js
const img = new Image();
img.onload = draw;
img.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbEMh.png';

function draw() {
  const ctx = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('2d');
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

To draw the image at a different size you can use

```
ctx.drawImage(img, x, y, width, height);
```

[image]

```js
const img = new Image();
img.onload = draw;
img.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbEMh.png';

function draw() {
  const ctx = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('2d');
  const destX = 10;
  const destY = 20;
  const destWidth = 30;
  const destHeight = 40;
  ctx.drawImage(img, destX, destY, destWidth, destHeight);
}
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

To draw part of the image you can use

```
// part of image to draw
const srcX = 10;
const srcY = 20;
const srcWidth = 130;
const srcHeight = 140;

// where to draw it
const dstX = 60;
const dstY = 70;
const dstWidth = 160;
const dstHeight = 40;

ctx.drawImage(img, srcX, srcY, srcWidth, srcHeight,
              dstX, dstY, dstWidth, dstHeight);
```

[image]

```js
const img = new Image();
img.onload = draw;
img.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbEMh.png';

function draw() {
  const ctx = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('2d');
  
  // part of image to draw
  const srcX = 10;
  const srcY = 20;
  const srcWidth = 130;
  const srcHeight = 140;

  // where to draw it
  const dstX = 60;
  const dstY = 70;
  const dstWidth = 160;
  const dstHeight = 40;

  ctx.drawImage(img, srcX, srcY, srcWidth, srcHeight,
                dstX, dstY, dstWidth, dstHeight);
}
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

That said, "fillRect" being ambiguous maybe you wanted to use the image as a pattern in which case you need to make a pattern out of it using [`createPattern`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/createPattern)

```
const pattern = ctx.createPatttern(img, 'repeat');
```

For these let's use this 16x16 pixel image

[image]

You can then use the pattern as your fillStyle as in

```
ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
ctx.fillRect(10, 20, 30, 40);
```

[image]

```js
const img = new Image();
img.onload = draw;
img.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlmSe.png';

function draw() {
  const ctx = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('2d');
  
  const pattern = ctx.createPattern(img, 'repeat');
  
  ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
  ctx.fillRect(10, 20, 30, 40);
}
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Patterns are relative to the origin of the canvas which means if you just use `ctx.fillRect` (or any other fill) the pattern will match across fills.

```
ctx.fillRect(10, 20, 30, 40);
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(50, 60, 25, 0, Math.PI * 2);
ctx.fill();
```

[image]

```js
const img = new Image();
img.onload = draw;
img.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlmSe.png';

function draw() {
  const ctx = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('2d');
  
  const pattern = ctx.createPattern(img, 'repeat');
  
  ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
  ctx.fillRect(10, 20, 30, 40);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(50, 60, 25, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.fill();
}
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Because patterns are anchored at the origin if you are animating without changing the origin you'll notice the pattern doesn't move

```js
const img = new Image();
img.onload = start;
img.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlmSe.png';

function start() {
  const ctx = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('2d');
  
  const pattern = ctx.createPattern(img, 'repeat');

  function render(time) {
    time *= 0.001;  // seconds;
    
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
    
    const x = Math.sin(time * 1.1) * 150 + 150;
    const y = Math.sin(time * 1.2) * 50 + 50;
    
    ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, 30, 40);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, 25, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fill();
    
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

In order to move the pattern you need to move the origin of the canvas using [`ctx.translate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/translate) (as well as [`ctx.rotate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/rotate), [`ctx.scale`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/scale), [`ctx.setTransform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/setTransform))

```js
const img = new Image();
img.onload = start;
img.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlmSe.png';

function start() {
  const ctx = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('2d');
  
  const pattern = ctx.createPattern(img, 'repeat');

  function render(time) {
    time *= 0.001;  // seconds;
    
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
    
    const x = Math.sin(time * 1.1) * 150 + 150;
    const y = Math.sin(time * 1.2) * 50 + 50;
    
    ctx.translate(x, y);
    
    ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 30, 40);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(0, 0, 25, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fill();
    
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);  // set it back to the default
    
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: This answer was very educational, and it helped me understand the question much better than the selected answer. Thank you for taking the time to type all of this out!

Answer (score 2):

Here's an illustration of some of the possibilities:

```
var im = new Image();
im.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/79/Face-smile.svg";
im.onload = function () { /* first, wait until the image is loaded */
    /* create five canvases, and draw something in each */
    for (var i=1; i<=5; i++) {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    canvas.width = canvas.height = 200;
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    var x=50, y=50; /* where to plot */
    var w=20, h=60; /* width and height of rectangle, if applicable */
    switch (i) {
    case 1:
        /* first canvas: draw a rectangle */
        ctx.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
        break;
    case 2:
        /* second canvas: draw an image, actual size, no clipping */
        /* coordinates are where the top left of the image is plotted */
        ctx.drawImage(im, x, y);
        break;
    case 3:
        /* third canvas: draw an image, scaled to rectangle */
        ctx.drawImage(im, x, y, w, h);
        break;
    case 4:
        /* fourth canvas: draw an image, actual size, clipped to rectangle */
        ctx.save();
        ctx.rect(x, y, w, h);
        ctx.clip();
        ctx.drawImage(im, x, y);
        ctx.restore();
        break;
    case 5:
        /* fifth canvas: draw shapes filled with a background image */
        ctx.fillStyle = ctx.createPattern(im, 'repeat'); /* or 'no-repeat', or 'repeat-x', or 'repeat-y' */
        /* note that the image is tiled from the top left of the canvas */
        ctx.fillRect(x, y, w, h);

        /* also draw a circle, why not */
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(150, 150, 40, 0, Math.PI*2);
        ctx.fill();
        break;
    }
    }
}
im.onerror = function() { alert("failed to load image"); };
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/efeqjjno/